# How to check if a voip server setup on docker is working or not?

Tags: docker, ip-address, asterisk, voip, host

I have a docker image of FreePBX 12, Asterisk 13, Ubuntu 14.04 on Docker. 
The run command is 
***docker run --net=host -d -t jmar71n/freepbx***. 
Now I need to put the host ip address in a webserver and check if it works ?
But, what should I expect when I put my host ip address on the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, my apache server was over riding this. I needed to stop apache service and then the admin page opened for me.

```
service apache2 stop
```

Comment: The FreePBX admin page opens on stopping the webserver.